# Query fetches plain text and I want it to be a checkbox

Tags: google-sheets

You can take a look at the spreadsheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZP-YGVj9mEJhc9EC6nSAEsOIJpCBJ1RuwRjQt8uJS_s/edit?usp=sharing

On my first tab, which uses query, it populates TRUE/FALSE for F - U instead of a checkbox. Which is fine, but for aesthetics I'd rather it have the checkbox.

How can I remedy that?

I tried to format it after it populated by if another entry is added from the tabs the query is pulling from it throws an error because it won't override the checkboxes manually added.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

**With column F** (later you can copy/paste format from F to U)

1. Select the column/cell where you want the checkbox and go to Data >
   Data Validation.
2. On Data Validation select the checkbox option for criteria
3. Check Use custom cell values
4. Set Checked=TRUE Unchecked=FALSE

Lastly apply the style on the remaining columns.

**UPDATE:**

Applied the validadtion/format whitin this range:

> 'N Facilitator'!F2:U17

Comment: That's the problem -- if I do that, it gives me this error on A1:
"Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in F2."

Comment: What A1 has to do ? that error makes sense since you are trying to apply the conditional for text,number and boolean columns. Cant you just do it on column F ?

Comment: A1 is the query. It refuses to run and overwrite the data on column F, which is the data validation for checkboxes.

Unless I'm doing it wrong. Were you able to get it to work?

Comment: it is readonly :(

Comment: Changed it to edit.

Comment: is it ok that you are passing two items in the array (thats the error) ? what query do you need ?

Comment: see the answer Update, it is working on my end, make it readonly asap :)

Comment: When you add students to the other pages, it doesn't do the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Added one [possible approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZP-YGVj9mEJhc9EC6nSAEsOIJpCBJ1RuwRjQt8uJS_s/edit#gid=163405420) here for you to test out:

```
={query({Smith_Leon!A:U; Jones_Amanda!A:U},"Select * Where Col4='N'");
  {makearray(2000,5,lambda(r,c,iferror(1/0))),makearray(2000,16,lambda(r,c,false))}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the assist!

I can't figure out the difference between your sheet and the N facilitator -- why it works on your sheet and not on mine. When I change the query formula to yours I still get that reference error.

Comment: Using the `makearray` part in the formula I am generating 2000 rows*16 columns of `FALSE` data **prior to** applying the tick box validation on all those cells. In your original scenario the tick box is applied on data cells (containing TRUE/FALSE) + empty cells beforehand and its resulting in the error when data expands into empty cells.

Comment: For some reason it didn't work when I implemented the formula, then the validation -- it gave the reference error. But when I ctrl+Z'd it worked for some reason...

Comment: **Step 1**: When you add the above formula you'll have lets say 20 rows of query data + 2K rows of faux data (with ***false*** notation) **Step 2**: Now strictly add the tick box validation for ONLY these 2020 rows where the ***true/false*** values are visible. Do not apply tickbox validation for row 2021 and beyond.